# Ionic: how can I scroll to bottom of the page without the scrolling animation?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

its'a chat page, I am scrolling to the bottom of the page on

```
ionViewDidEnter


 ionViewDidEnter(){

    this.content.scrollToBottom();

 }
```

I would like it scroll to the bottom without the scrolling animation, in other words just show the bottom of the page like whatsapp chat. when you click on a chat, it scrolls down to the recent chat to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that would be by using the `scrollDownOnLoad` **[input property](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/content/Content/#input-properties)** from the `ion-content`:

```
<ion-content scrollDownOnLoad="true">
...
</ion-content>
```

If you want to have more control over **when** the content scrolls to the bottom of the page, but you don't want to show any animations during the scroll, you can set the duration of the `scrollTobottom()` method to be 0 like this:

```
this.content.scrollToBottom(0); // The default is 300ms
```

Comment: thank you! scrollToBottom(0); eliminates the scroll animation, however there is still the top to bottom movement. I tried "scrollDownOnLoad="true"" but that doesn't do anything

Comment: What happens if you load the data and use the `scrollToBottom()` in the  `ionViewDidLoad` hook instead of the `ionViewDidEnter`?

Comment: `scrollToBottom()` only works on `ionViewDidEnter` but not on `ionViewDidload`

Comment: I am loading all the data in `ionViewWillEnter` and then using `scrollToBottom(0)` in `ionViewDidLoad`

Comment: Another way to solve this could be to get all the messages in the previous page, and send them to the next page using `NavParams`. That way you can get the messages in the `ionViewWillLoad` from the second page, and using the `scrollDownOnLoad="true"` should work because the messages will be there when the page finishes loading.